# pst-map3d not found and not availble in apt repositories

Tags: packages, pstricks, ctan, pst-geo

I encounter the following error while testing pst-map3d:
`! LaTeX Error: File 'pst-map3d.sty' not found.`

And `apt` cannot find it:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search pst-map3d
$
```

I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

My final goal is to draw to 3D geographics stuff with merdians, parallels, [local tangent plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_tangent_plane_coordinates) and so on, such as this simple figure in a first stage:

[image: local tangent plane]

Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ECEF_ENU_Longitude_Latitude_relationships.svg

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-map3d}

\begin{document}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

Is this package deprecated?

#### EDIT:

`texlive-pstricks` is already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install texlive-pstricks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-pstricks is already the newest version (2017.20180305-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
```

#### More info

Package homepage:
https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/pst-map3d/

Related CTAN entry I found:
https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-geo

Notice; the same error appears if I append `\usepackage{pst-geo}` to the preamble.

Comment: You should install it by hand in your `TeXmf-local` (in a TDS architecture).

Comment: TDS:= Tex Directory Structure (http://tug.ctan.org/tds/tds.html#Introduction)

Comment: Ok, I will try this without messing all my tex stuff. But before that, do you know if there is some kind of package manager for LaTeX, which for example could download and install them properly and automatically from CTAN. A sort of `apt` or `pip` tool, but for latex?

Comment: Unfortunatly, I know none, except for the packages from official distributions. It is not very complicated, though: the documentation in `TeXmf-local\doc\latex\pst-map3d`, the .tex and .pro files in `TeXmf-local\tex\generic\pst-map3d` and the .sty file in `TeXmf-local\tex\latex\pst-map3d`.

Comment: Seems good, but while compiling [this](https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/B/BasePstricks/pst-map3d/globes/tv02.tex) example with TexMaker 5.0.2, I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PstEH.png) during Quick Build (configured as: "PdfLaTeX + View PDF" in the TexMaker "Options > Configure Texmaker" menu).

Comment: The previous issue was solved by also copying the `map3d.pro` file into the `TeXmf-local/dvips/pst-map3d/` folder.

Comment: Oh! yes. I forgot to check this point, but you don't need the postscript prologues in TeXmf-local\tex\generic, since they're not TeX code,  only  in TeXmf-local\dvips as you did.

Answer (score 1):

Install `sudo apt-get install texlive-pstricks`

Comment: `texlive-pstricks` is already installed. See edits. Thanks for pointing that out.